# Blender addon development

Tags: modeling, add-on, workflow, development

I have a hard modelling addon idea for blender. I have no coding experience and have no idea where to even start with learning coding or what I need to learn. It's an add on building on an existing function in blender which I guess all addons are haha. Could someone point me in the correct direction to learn to code an addon ? Or an easier option for me would someone like to support me and help me build it ? I think it could be quite successful as I am a digital modeller and the function I want to create does not exist in the way I want it. Thanks for reading ! Any help would be really appreciated!!

Have a good day,

Max

Answer (score 1):

Prepare for a long journey. Start small. Aim to have something functional and complete, but simple, as soon as possible.

Here's a good intro on Python: https://automatetheboringstuff.com/

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/advanced/scripting/addon_tutorial.html gives a good overview of writing a simple addon.

I personally learned Blender addons best with Michel's tutorials. Since then he wrote a book about it. The old tutorials seem to be gone. https://blendermarket.com/products/creating-add-ons-for-blender

After you've learned everything, you need a good ref: https://docs.blender.org/api/current/index.html https://docs.python.org/3/reference/

And of course, as all addons for Blender are open source, go and open the folder of your favorite addon and start reading.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! I will check it out. What I want to do seems simple and I think I understand the logic to make it happen just no coding experience.